# Java AWT applet white screen when resizing window

Tags: java, applet, awt

I have a java applet built using awt.

I draw some text on a panel object and everything goes fine.
but when resizing the windows all the text disappears.

this behaviour is different among different jvms and platforms.

moving to swing isn't a possible option, because we have to maintain compatiblty with Microsoft JVM.

Comment: *"we have to maintain compatiblty with Microsoft JVM."* (Sings) *"I'm gonna' program like it's nineteen ninety-nine!"* (with apologies to Prince).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try attaching a ComponentListener which then calls paint() from within componentResized().

Something like:

```
class MyPanel extents Panel implements ComponentListner {
    public MyPanel() {
        addComponentListener(this);
    }
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        paint(getGraphics());
    }
}
```

**Update:** you should probably call 'repaint()' rather than directly invoking paint().

Answer (score 1):

You must override `update(Graphics g)` and render your text in there. This method will be called when the window needs to be redrawn.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your code, we have to guess, but is it possible that your text drawing is not being done in a `paint()` method? [Read this](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/) for details on how AWT painting works.